If abcd is cylic and e is a point on the line ab so de is parallel to cb, how do i prove the circumcircle of triangle dae touches dc
If abcd is cylic and e is a point on the line ab (it can be produced if necessary) so de is parallel to cb, how do i prove the circumcircle of triangle dae touches dc

What have you tried? If the circumcircle is tangential, what is 1 set of angles that must be equal? How can we angle chase to show that they are equal?

i simply drew it out and im stuck, i dont know how to proceed

I think it is pure angle chasing.

Let Angle ABC be $a$, then by cyclic quadrilateral we will get angle ADC as $180^0 - a$. Now let Angle BAC be $b$, then angle BAD will be $180^0-b$. Now by linear angles sum to $180^0$ we will get that angle DAE is $b$. Now as we know de is parallel to cb we get angle ADE as $a-b$. Then we get angle DEA as $180^0-a$. From this we get Angle EDL where L is the line on which cd is lying as $b$.
From here we can conclude that angle AED angle ADC are equal and similarly we can get that angle EAD and angle EDL equal. This is a property when L is tangent to circumcircle of DAE.( A expansion of Tangent Secant Theorem)
Therefore we can say that circumcircle of DAE is touching CD
